# Java Fx Scatter Chart more symbols needed for my data

Tags: java, javafx, charts

i am currently trying to create an scatter chart with 16 datapoints. My Problem is that if the chart is created there are only 8 different symbols for the other 8 datapoints the symbols and colors just repeate themself. Maybe you guys cold help me out. Here is the code i use :

```
//Create Scatter Chart to visualize the Data
    Stage test2 = new Stage();

    test2.setTitle(titel+" optimization Powersag Pupil Ring + FineRes Pupil Ring");
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(50, 100, 75);
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 0.5, 0.25);
    final ScatterChart<Number, Number> sc = new ScatterChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
    xAxis.setLabel("±0,50 D Group [%]");
    yAxis.setLabel("MedAE");

    sc.setTitle(titel+" optimization Powersag Pupil Ring + FineRes Pupil Ring");
    int tmp2 = 1;
    for (int i =8; i <A_const.size();i++) {

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();




        series1.setName("Power sag Pupil Ring: " + tmp2 + ".0mm");


        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(group_list.get(i), median_list.get(i)));




        sc.getData().addAll(series1);
        tmp2++;



    }





    //FineREs
    tmp2=0;
    for (int i =8; i <A_const.size();i++) {

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();



        series1.setName("Fine Res Pupil Ring: " + "2."+tmp2+"mm");
        tmp2++;


        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(group_list_fineres.get(i), median_list_fineres.get(i)));


        sc.getData().addAll(series1);

    }
    Scene scene = new Scene(sc, 500, 400);
    test2.setScene(scene);
    test2.show();
```

Comment: basically, you have to replace the style of the nodes, see f.i. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294879/how-can-i-change-the-icon-in-javafx-linechart-above-the-7th-series-in-css - depending on how dynamic your data is, doing it once after config might be enough or subclass scatterChart and implement seriesAdded and/or dataItemAdded to replace the style as needed.

Comment: BTW: you might consider putting a bit more effort into your question - best to provide code as [mcve], properly formatted and following java naming conventions.

Comment: If you want a different symbol for each point, CSS is probably not the way to go. Consider using [`setNode()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#setNode(javafx.scene.Node)) (which I generally hate; the view should not be a property of the data, but the API is what it is).

Comment: Also consider [tag:jfreechart-fx] and a custom `DrawingSupplier` having 16 unique `Shape` instances, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20DrawingSupplier%20Shape)

Answer (score 0):

i used an css file to define the colors for the series:

```
.series0.chart-symbol{-fx-background-color: black}
.series1.chart-symbol{-fx-background-color: silver}
.series2.chart-symbol{-fx-background-color: gray}
.series3.chart-symbol{-fx-background-color: white}
.series4.chart-symbol{-fx-background-color: maroon}
.series5.chart-symbol{-fx-background-color: red}
```

This worked for me !

Comment: interesting: you get the same symbols with different colors? Looks a bit unpredictable, though, for production you'll probably need to find out how exactly the combination is determined. Reminder: please edit the question to format the code properly and fix the naming violations :)